# How to secure a WCF service for Project Server?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, web-services, project-server

I have a WCF service that collects and return the data from a Project Server database. The service will be online, so not everyone should have access to the service. What kind of security or authentication should I implement ?

Answer (score 1):

Integrated Domain Security See MSDN WCF Security Page

I would run the application in a group or as user with the minimum required privileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx

If the machines are in a Virtual Machine you could even technically create a named pipe end point and then expose it to the children machines... but this is more advanced and you lose some of the options with TCP bindings.

You could also create a loop back adapter on the Host Machine and then use that adapter to forward to the service end point depending on origin. You would then expose the adapter to the children..

It all depends on how important security is and what you are trying to achieve in the end... e.g. is mobile going to be a concern...

Comment: An application will use the wcf service to collect data from a project server database. The application will be installed on several machines. As the service will be online, only my application should be able to use the service. Any others attempting to use the service should not receive any data from the service.

Comment: I would not expose the service on a public IP or a machine with public network access. I would additionally utilize named pipe endpoints to enforce this requirements and I would do it as I stated above... if you needed TcpBinding then use a loop back with forwarding rules or a forwarding service as an additional layer.

Comment: I am doing a research based on your answers. Up vote is for the most helpful answer ... (seriously ?!)

Comment: Well it is the best answer :P Notice anyone had anything else much to say but take your time :p